# Does Solana have cluster id similar to Ethereum network id?

Tags: cluster, network

Does Solana have cluster id similar to Ethereum network id, for purpose of distinguishing different networks?

Comment: Do you mean detecting the cluster when you are inside the smart contract?

Comment: sort of. I mean if I setup a private cluster, for example, how to keep it isolated from mainnet-beta? will transactions be mixed or dispatched to wrong net/cluster?

Comment: A cluster is just a set of validators that maintain the same ledger, starting from the same genesis block. If you don't share the genesis block with the main clusters, then it won't join those.

Comment: I better post it as an answer before mods come down on us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we teased out that the ask is whether running a private cluster has the risk of accidentally joining another cluster.

A Solana cluster is essentially a set of validators that maintain the same ledger, starting from the same genesis block.

If a private cluster has a different genesis block, it is unlikely other clusters will accept its comms.